# setting up for loop to count

Tags: python, loops, count

I am:

1. getting user input in the form of a string.
2. using a nested for loop to count the number of times each letter would appear.

For now, assume everything is lower case.

This is the desired output that I am seeking.

```
please enter a sentence: this is a test

a : 1

e : 1

h : 1

i : 2

s : 3

t : 3
```

So far in Python, I can get this far:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
```

I know that the answer will need a counter and a nested for loop.

```
for alpha in

['a','b','c',........,'z']:
```

Comment: As a side note, you can `import string` and then just do `for alpha in string.ascii_lowercase:`.

Comment: Anyway, here's a hint: Inside that loop, you want to find out how many times `alpha` appears in `sentence`, right? So, you can do `for alpha2 in sentence:`, and then compare `if alpha == alpha2:`. What can you do from there?

Comment: Thanks so much abarnert that actually helps me out a lot. this is for a computer programming project it is not the full question so no worries there. but i was unable to figure out how to structure the for loop, we have only talked about for loops with integers and floats not so much with strings and letters and stuff.

Comment: my first time ever here asking a question and i am getting down voted thanks for the support guys. i have only started computer programming class this semester. i am not a pro :(.

Comment: Downvotes are not a reflection on you as a person, they are reflection on whether your question makes the site (a repository of questions with good, widely-useful answers) better or worse. If you're going to take things personally like this, you are not going to get much help out of Stack Overflow. I gave you a hint, Jared Reeves gave you an answer that probably isn't what you want plus a hint that probably is, you came out of it ahead, right?

Comment: yes you have helped the most so far and i get the 'for alpha2 in sentence' but i am not sure how to tie the user input sentence = input("the input: ") with the alpha in [a,b,c] with the comparison   will i have to make a loop or comparison for every letter in the alphabet.

Comment: There are ways to avoid comparing every letter of the sentence with every letter of the alphabet, e.g., by turning one of those sequences into a `set` or `dict` so it can do the lookup instantly instead of with an extra loop. But I wouldn't worry about that yet. You haven't been taught any of that yet, and you were apparently directly asked to write two nested loops, so the fact that two nested loops aren't the absolute most efficient or concise way to do this isn't a problem.

Comment: Actually, after you write the code, if you can figure out _why_ the nested loops make you feel uncomfortable, and ask your teacher why the version with `Counter` is so much faster, you might learn something, and impress your teacher. Then again, you might also just annoy your teacher by jumping ahead and disrupting his rigid lesson plan; you probably know him better than me and can decide for yourself. :)

Comment: lol her rigid lesson plan. trust me i would like to jump ahead on some things. we spent the first 3 weeks talking about strings and integers and floats which was easy and should have taken like 1 week and then we spent 3 days on for loops and nested for loops and now we get a project that uses them. also we never discussed alpha or for loops with strings much at all. i printed out some stuff that should help me and then i am also going to go over the book again and see if it helps much. thanks.

Comment: @trenten your teacher might have spent a little bit to much time on the basic data types, but you need to remember everything else in programming is built upon these base types. They are the foundation to build on. Also remember, that although you need to do the work, you can learn more about the higher level concepts on your own. Being able to learn new things on your own will make you a better programmer

Comment: i agree but i am the type of person to not take an answer and continue i will look at it until i reverse engineer it and understand it that said this is where i am. 'sentence = "this is a test" 

for abc in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']:
    for letters in sentence:
        if abc == letters:
            print (abc)'

Comment: never mind i am somewhat skipping this question i did it but not the way she wanted i just used a ton of if statements lol it works but it is not pretty the project is only worth 20 points and we had a 100 point exam last week and i got a 94 percent on it so no worries on the grade. i am more irritated that i couldn't figure this out more than anything with the for loops. i am now moving on to the second part of the project. lol here is how i murdered it  if (sentence.count('a') > 0):
    print ("a :", sentence.count('a'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the built in [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) function in the collection module.

just import counter from the collections module and then do this:

```
cString = Counter(SomeString)
#return the cString object

#returns the object in order of occurrence.
cString.most_common
```

**Edit:**

However, if this is, like I assume, for homework and you need to do it in the most basic way( and without giving you the answer) these are the steps you will need to take.

1. Build a function that takes a string as a param
2. Have an array that contains all of the characters of the alphabet
3. For each item in the alpha array compare item to each item in input string to get the count of occurrences
4. Add key value pair of character and count to dictionary
5. Return/print the dictionary

Comment: This doesn't fit the requirement of "painfully basic", especially without an explanation of how it works. It also doesn't provide the designed output, which is clearly in alphabetical order, not most common to least, and it's hard to imagine the OP will figure out how to do that without help.

Comment: I would call this basic but, I also assumed that this was for some sort of homework. Thus I gave the an answer of how I would accomplish this. Yes it is out of spec but I gave this in case I am mistaken and it is not for homework.

Comment: thanks guys an i am needing help structuring it. this is a question for a school project but it is not the full question this is just a very small part of the question i just am not sure how to structure the for loop i can get the input(easy), then i am not sure how to use the for alpha in ['a','b',....,'z'] part in a for loop to display the output in alphabetical order going down without showing the ones with no characters i think i will need a for loop to count it but we can't use import string, or any count mod. just basic for loops. which we have hardly talked about yet.

Comment: You will need to have one loop on outside to loop over alpha list, and one inner loop(over the string) that will check/count the string against the current position of the alpha. Does this help?

Comment: thanks i will give it a shot tonight the project is due thursday but. i think i can figure out the second part. we just just learned for loops and nested for loops at that so that is why i wasn't sure about how to set this up. thanks for the replies. i will come back here if i need any more help

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = input("Enter the sentence: ")
count = 0

sentence = sentence.lower()

for letters in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']:
    for letter in sentence:
            if letters == letter:
                count += 1
    if (count != 0):
        print (letters,":",count)
        count = 0
```